# Does Mathematica have a plug-in for communicating with an Android device?

Tags: interoperability

I am trying to take input from an Android device, do some processing in *Mathematica* and pass the final output back to the device, so I need a plug in to communicate to an Android device.

Comment: It seems to be possible to use the [Pebble SDK](http://developer.getpebble.com/blog/2015/01/16/Pebble-And-Wolfram/), so Android should be similar.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77514/8822

Comment: Actually I want to call as a function for Mathematica code in Android .Is there any other way without using Wolfram cloud because it will take more time and every time need internet connection

Comment: I am asking like to use Mathematica function in android possibility?