# Is there a Function like Here or FindGeoLocation[] that pulls GPS from an Android device for Wolfram Cloud deployments?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, geodesy, cloud-deploy

Neither `FindGeoLocation[]` nor `Here` really work when deploying to the cloud for a mobile or browser app.

```
CloudDeploy[
 APIFunction[{}, {FindGeoLocation[], Here} &], "Where_am_I?"]
```

Instead of using the device or browser location, these functions use the Wolfram Cloud servers' GeoIP and `$GeoLocation`, respectively.  Is there a way to get the browser or device GPS location?

Ideally, `$GeoLocation` would sync with device GPS so that deployments could still use `Here` and support `Dynamic[Here]`, maybe?...

I'm aware of this good post: [Capturing Data from an Android Phone](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77514/capturing-data-from-an-android-phone) -- so I could have the application retrieve the GPS field from Data Drop, but that seems like an ugly hack.

Has anyone dealt with this or found a solution?  Thanks!