# Improving accuracy of $GeoLocation in wolfram cloud forms

Tags: wolfram-cloud, geography, input-forms

The four commands

```
Here

CloudEvaluate[Here]

CloudEvaluate[FindGeoLocation[]]

CloudEvaluate[$GeoLocation]
```

all give wildly different results. None of them are correct (some even showing a different country). I assume that `CloudEvaluate[Here]` gives the location of the Wolfram Cloud server, but why is that different from the other `CloudEvaluate` commands?

I wish to create a `FormPage` in the Wolfram cloud where I can enter some data via my phone, including the phone's current location. How do I access the phone's GPS readings from a Wolfram cloud `FormPage`?

Comment: I thought that this one is a duplicate [116508](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116508/5478) but the fact it is about `APIFunction` not a `FormPage` makes it different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work well, it will ask you to give permissions to access gps data and then our JS will initialize `"yourPosition"` field with coordinates taken from `navigator` (see: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

```
    CloudDeploy[
      FormPage[{
        EmbeddedHTML @ StringJoin[
          "<script>function initYourPosition( position ) { document.getElementsByName('yourPosition')[0].value = ''+position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude;}</script>"
        , "<script>navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initYourPosition)</script>"
        ]
      , "yourPosition"->"GeoCoordinates"
      }
      , GeoGraphics[{ GeoMarker[#], Inset[#2,#]}& @@@ {
          {Here,"\nHere"},
          {$GeoLocation,"$GeoLocation"},
          {FindGeoLocation[],"FindGeoLocation"},
          {FindGeoLocation[$RequesterAddress],"by requester address"},
          {#yourPosition,"navigator.geolocation"}
         },
        GeoRange->Quantity[6,"Kilometers"],
        GeoZoomLevel->Automatic,
        GeoCenter->#yourPosition
      ] &
    ]
    , CreateUUID["temp/"]
    , Permissions -> "Public"
    ]
```

And the final result after allowing access and submitting:

[image]

I found a a Community.wolfram.com post that does even more: [Exact GeoPosition from FormFunction](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1576753) but requires a little bigger html+js template.